# Lower bound for $bb(7)$ - which one is true ? And what is the bound for $bb(6,3)$?

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines, big-numbers

- $bb(7)$ is already extremely large , but I found a discrepancy in the lower bound:

  In this [survey](https://sites.google.com/site/googology63556/busy-beaver-function) the lower bound for $bb(7)$ is given as
  $$
  BB(7) > 10^{10^{10^{10^7}}},
  $$ hence four tens in the power tower followed by a 7.

  But [here](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/User:Wythagoras/Rado%27s_sigma_function/BB(7)) there are five tens in the power tower followed by a $7$. Which one is true ?
- With $6$ states and $3$ symbols, the lower bound is HUGE, but I wonder whether I interprete the notation correctly :
  Is the bound [here](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/User:Wythagoras/Rado%27s_sigma_function/BB(6,3)) i.e. $$2\uparrow^6 8$$ in Knuth Arrow notation ?

A clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower bound for $BB(7)$ is the one given in the initial announcement

$$ BB(7) > 10^{10^{10^{10^{18705352}}}} > 10^{10^{10^{10^{10^7}}}}, $$

as confirmed by Cloudy176 and P. Michel in the links posted therein.

The notation used for $BB(6,3)$ is indeed $2 \uparrow^6 8$. The braces indicate Bowers' Exploding Array Notation, which up to three entries correspond with arrow notation as $\{a, b, c\} = a \uparrow^c b$. Also see the explanation posted below in the link, there some explanation is given using Knuth's arrow notation.

Comment: Thank you, so five tens is actually correct ! Do you happen to know a bound for $BB(5,3)$ ?

Comment: Getting to BB(5,3) is quite difficult, since one either needs to provide input using 1 state to the Ackermannian growth machine on which the BB(6,3) bound is based, or program repeated exponentiation/tetration with only 3 states or find some clever way to combine it with giving input. The bound for BB(4,3) is found by a computer search and it would be very hard for a human to come up with such a machine (in fact, it is already quite a task to analyze it, after it was found by the computer), so it isn't weird that there is a "gap".

Comment: Note that some more bounds can be found [here](http://googology.fandom.com/wiki/User:Wythagoras/Rado's_sigma_function?oldid=109741), an older version of my user page (but it is quite outdated, for example the bounds given for BB(6,3) and BB(7,3) are much weaker than those I found later)

Comment: Great ! Thank you for those insights. I just wondered whether $BB(5,3)$ is already huge.

Comment: It probably is. Actually, note that the BB(7) machine is only a slight variation on the BB(6) machine (the additional state is only used once), so it is not unreasonable to guess that BB(6) is already larger than a high stack of exponentials. I would similarly expect BB(4,3), BB(3,4) and BB(2,6) to be larger than a high stack of exponentials. (We don't yet know whether increasing colors or states is better, but at this moment there are no strong reasons to expect a specific one among these (which can all use 12 transitions) to be much larger or smaller than others).

Comment: But even the current exponential-sized bounds for BB(6), BB(4,3), BB(3,4) and BB(2,6) already require quite special/difficult techniques to simulate. When going to doubly exponential or beyond, we cannot even store the exact tape configuration anymore using tape exponents (e.g. for BB(6) we can write the final tape as 111(011)^k, where k is a 18268-digit number, so it can be written out in full), so we would need to turn to "approximate" simulation to find (much) larger bounds than the current bounds.

Comment: Another question about huge numbers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347830/where-in-the-fast-growing-hierarchy-is-the-next-level-beyond-latri)